# Touchstart en Touchmove dont work together with multi-touches

Tags: javascript, touch, touch-event

I have a really weird problem and i cant seem to figure out what is causing it. My problem is that when i have a touchstart event fire it no longer lets a touchmove event fire. I tried a lot of different things even things like converting it completely to hammerJS with no luck.

A jsBin example of my problem: http://jsbin.com/ayibeq/8/

**Touch events:**

```
 steering_wheel.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e){
      steering_wheel_rotate(steering_wheel,e);      
  });
  gas_paddle.addEventListener("touchstart",function(e){
    keyFaster = true;
    keySlower = false;
  });
  gas_paddle.addEventListener("touchend",function(e){
    keyFaster = false;
    keySlower = true;
  });
  break_paddle.addEventListener("touchstart",function(e){
    keySlower = true;
    keyFaster = false;
  });
  break_paddle.addEventListener("touchend",function(e){
    keySlower = true;
    keyFaster = false;
  });
```

I so far have managed to figure out that it has something to do with touchmove happening after touchstart. So if you first use the steering wheel and then one of the gas paddles its fine but when you use the gas paddles first and then the steering wheel it no longer works.

Its probably something really silly i am overlooking.

**Update**
I so far have managed to narrow it down to be only be a problem with android 4.1 and 4.2 devices. IOS 4+ has no issues with the way its done now.